# I can't run python3 program in vim

Tags: python-3.x, vim

I did a very simple program :

```
a = input("Enter a number A : ")

b = input("Enter a number B : ")

print("Below 2 strings concateneted :")

print(a + b)
```

1. When i run it from bash, i write :

```
python3 <my_program.py>
```

It works well

2. When i run it from vim, i open "my_program.py" in vim and then write :

```
:w !python3
```

It crashes and gives me this message :

```
Enter a number A : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

3. when i run it from a terminal opened from vim, i write :

```
:terminal
```

then

```
python3 <my_program.py>
```

This works.

Why i can't execute python3 programs from vim ?

EDIT : it's linked with the input function. If i directly assign variables it works. More information are welcome.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to execute it from vim?

Comment: I wanted to execute quickly code in vim execution bar for debug purposes. But there is no choice : open terminal in vim and then execute code. A pity!

Comment: you are doing `:w !python3`, why not just `:!python3 my_program.py`? What are you trying to accomplish with the `:w`?

Comment: I just saved my last changes. But it has no impact on the topic. the conclusion so far is that you can  run python code in vim (it works)....But at least the function input() will not work (no handover). Try on your side, you'll get the same result.

Comment: It works just fine for me to do `:!python3 my_program.py`. It also works to open a python terminal by doing just `:!python3`. I get the same error as you only when I try to write and call python at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the input function in my python script.

Because i want to keep this function. No choice, open a separate terminal.

By the way, it's be possible to open the terminal in VIM (for convenience) writing in VIM normal mode :

```
:vert term
```